# Why can't the ViewModel object be created automatically when I use Hilt as Dependency Injection in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt

The following Code A is from the official sample [project](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-compose-codelabs/tree/main/AdvancedStateAndSideEffectsCodelab).

The project use Hilt as Dependency Injection.

In my mind, I needn't create the `ViewModel` object by myself because Hilt will create it automatically.

But in Code A, it seems that `viewModel: MainViewModel = viewModel()` must be created manually, why?

**Code A**

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
@Composable
fun CraneHomeContent(
    onExploreItemClicked: OnExploreItemClicked,
    openDrawer: () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    viewModel: MainViewModel = viewModel(),
) {

   ...
}



@HiltViewModel
class MainViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val destinationsRepository: DestinationsRepository,
    @DefaultDispatcher private val defaultDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher
) : ViewModel() {

   ...
}


@HiltAndroidApp
class CraneApplication : Application()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By creating manually, I mean calling the view model constructor. And this is not practiced with Hilt, because you have to pass down all the injections.

You can't just declare the `viewModel: MainViewModel` parameter, because then you have to pass it from the calling view.

The `viewModel()` does all the injection magic for you. Also, if the view model already exists, the same object will be returned. So it's completely automatic.